# Raw Input and cursor acceleration

Tags: windows, winapi, raw-input

I'm currently implementing mouse input using Raw input.
The disadvantage though is, that pointer ballistic is not included. Unfortunately microsoft's website dealing with this topic is not online any more. Furthermore I can't find a function retrieving the pointer acceleration set in windows (maybe I'm too stupid).

How do I get the acceleration and how do I use it to calculate the new intuitive cursor position out of the raw x and y offset?

**EDIT:**

So concerning the documentation IInspectable posted in his comment, the code for calculating the acceleration would be:

```
    long xPos = raw->data.mouse.lLastX;
    long yPos = raw->data.mouse.lLastY;

    int speed;
    int acceleration[3];
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETMOUSESPEED, 0, &speed, 0);
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETMOUSE, 0, acceleration, 0);


    if (acceleration[2] > 0 && acceleration[0] < abs(raw->data.mouse.lLastX))
        xPos *= 2;
    else if (acceleration[2] > 1 && acceleration[1] < abs(raw->data.mouse.lLastX))
        xPos *= 2;

    if (acceleration[2] > 0 && acceleration[0] < abs(raw->data.mouse.lLastX))
        yPos *= 2;
    else if (acceleration[2] > 1 && acceleration[1] < abs(raw->data.mouse.lLastX))
        yPos *= 2;


    xPos *= round((float)speed / 10.0f);
    yPos *= round((float)speed / 10.0f);
```

Am I right, is this how to add acceleration to the raw mouse input?

Strange is, that when I retrieve acceleration with SystemParametersInfo and SPI_GETMOUSE the values stay at {6, 10, 1} even if I change the pointer acceleration in windows.

Comment: You query the mouse acceleration by calling [SystemParametersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947.aspx) with an `SPI_GETMOUSE` parameter. Information on mouse acceleration is available in the *Remarks* section of the [mouse_event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260.aspx) documentation.

Comment: Microsoft's article on `Pointer Ballistics for Windows XP` has been available on the Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20101222190833/http://www.microsoft.com:80/whdc/archive/pointer-bal.mspx

Answer (score 0):

I have a single function that does this scaling, for an arbitrary delta (dq), and it is similar to yours. However, my experience is that Windows acceleration and pointer enhancement, in particular when there's DPI awareness to take into account, makes the mapping between RAWINPUT and what a corresponding WM_MOUSEMOVE would see, very tricky...

```
int ApplyMouseAcceleration(int dq)
{
    auto absdq{ abs(dq) };
    // based on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx
    if (MouseAccelerationparams[0] && absdq > MouseAccelerationparams[0])   
    {
        dq *= 2;
        if ((absdq > MouseAccelerationparams[1]) && (MouseAccelerationparams[2] == 2))
        {
            dq *= 2;
        }                                       
    }
    dq = (dq*MouseSpeed) / 10;
    return dq;
}
```

Comment: Actually; the "enhanced pointer movement" setting in Windows is the culprit; it appears to introduce another set of modifiers somewhere that are *not* the acceleration curve you get from SPI_GETMOUSE etc. I can't find where this is documented, so perhaps it isn't... :(